# Creating a Interface for Insering Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, interface

I am trying to create a site that has option to add maps to the site using google maps api. I found hundreds of tutorial and blog posts on embeding map in the site. But what I actually want is a way to give the user choose a place on the map and add marker. Then get the co-ordinates of the marker and store it in the database of retrieving and showing in the front-end. I have seen this option given wordpress plugins like mappress. But now I'm trying to achieve this in codeigniter. I can't find any thing to start on. Can any one point out some one tell me where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really easy the 3rd version of the [Google maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html).  Versions before that where much more complicated, and most of the tutorials floating around are for those versions.  Have a look through the API documentation and examples.

Adding a marker is as simple as:

```
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({/* ... see API */});
```

Adding an event (eg click) to a marker is as simple as:

```
var marker_click=new google.maps.event.addListener(
                       marker,
                       'click',
                       function() {/*...*/});
```

Sounds like you'd want a click event for the map, which you'd translate into a latlong, then (a) generate a marker on the map with JS, and (b) post that back to your server using AJAX, or by storing the values in a hidden form field to be submitted after.

**Update:**

Mostly from the API documentation @ http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function placeMarker(location) {
  var clickedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location, 
      map: map
  });

  map.setCenter(location);

  /*Do your processing here:
   * eg. ajax.post('addMarkerDB&lat='+location.lat+'&long='+location.long);
   */
}
```

**Note:** There is no ajax.post function by default, but there could be :)

Comment: Yes thats what i want to achieve... It would be great if I could getting a little more explanation. How the value is stored in a hidden field and all... really ignorant on this.